# How to make a webpage unresponsive?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm looking to make my webpage unresponsive in the sense to where upon a window resize, rather than elements changing properties & using media queries, I want the entire page to just scale down proportionally and all elements keep their ratio. How is this done? with pure css or with the aid of JS?

Comment: I think the text in the video just makes it confusing, because it's actually in an image.  So, likely all they're really doing is using percentage widths.

Comment: This can be accomplished by expressing all your units in terms of `vh` and `vw`. Also, since browsers generally tend to see a greater change in width than they do in height, consider using `vw` for your heights as well. This also works for font-sizes, paddings and margins too.

Comment: Have a look here- Try resizing the window. --- https://jsfiddle.net/129vyr4n/

Answer (score 1):

I'm no master at HTML, but maybe you could try percentages? as your values for your width,height,etc.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution on [this](https://northstreetcreative.com/notes/full-screen-website-zoom-using-css-transform-and-jquery/) page. I'm not sure if it will work exactly the same but it looks similar. There is a link to the demo on the site.